# Para o file_get_contents existem opções similares a essas do cURL?

Tags: php

Para o file_get_contents existem opções similares a essas do cURL?

```
$cookie_file = "cookie1.txt";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file); 
$str = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: Isso é uma pergunta ou uma afirmação? Isso aí vc tá pegando cookies apenas nada de conteúdo. E tá faltando inicializar esse request. Você executa algo que não foi inicializado

Comment: @Coruja, é uma pergunta. Não coloquei toda a função porque imaginei que ficaria confuso. Os opcionais que me faltam ao `file_get_contents`são apenas os do cookie. Se tiver algo completo que faça isso com o f_g_c, agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade pode até usar o [`Sockets`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.sockets.php) para isso, lógico que com o `file_gets_contents` também conseguirá.

É importante lembrar que no caso abaixo não estou utilizando o formato Netscape, usado pelo `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`. Não sei se isso é realmente necessário, em seu lugar estou usando o formato do próprio `Cookie:`, sendo `Nome=Valor;`.

---

*Pode ser que existam funções nativas, mas de todas as formas você conseguirá fazer isso "manualmente", que é o que irei fazer.*

---

### Obter os cookies:

Todos os cookies são enviados pelo servidor no cabeçalho da requisição, eles tem o nome de `Set-Cookie` e seu formato também é padrão. Neste caso queremos apenas o nome dele e o valor, então poderá fazer:

```
$resposta = file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1/teste.php');
if($resposta === false){
    exit();
}

$cookie = [];

foreach($http_response_header as $cabecalho){

    // Se o cabeçalho for "Set-Cookie:" iremos fazer...  
    if(mb_stripos($cabecalho, 'Set-Cookie:', 0, '8bit') === 0){

        // Se houver `;` pegamos tudo antes do primeiro `;`
        $string = mb_stristr($cabecalho, ';', true, '8bit');

        // Se não houver `;` então todo o cabeçalho é o próprio "Nome=Valor"
        if($string === false){
            $string = $cabecalho;
        }

        // Removemos o `Set-Cookie:` e adicionamos numa array:
        $cookie[] =  trim(mb_substr($string, 11, null, '8bit'));
    }
}

file_put_contents('cookies.txt', implode($cookie, '; '));
```

O `$http_response_header` obtem o cabeçalho da última solicitação, assim poderá ler todos os cabeçalhos, o array é divido por linha. Portanto, cada ciclo do `foreach` é uma linha. Cada cookie é enviado em linhas diferentes, com o mesmo nome `Set-Cookie`.

Você também pode usar outras soluções, inclusive uso de REGEX para mesmo finalidade acima, um outro exemplo seria:

```
//...
foreach($http_response_header as $cabecalho){
    if(mb_stripos($cabecalho, 'Set-Cookie:', 0, '8bit') === 0){
        $cookie[] =  trim(mb_substr(explode( ';', $cabecalho)[0], 11, null, '8bit'));
    }
}
//..
```

Já para salvarmos a informação utilizamos o `file_put_contents`, em ambos os casos:

```
file_put_contents('cookies.txt', implode($cookie, '; '));
```

Isso irá salvar todos os cookies no formato:

```
Nome=Valor; NomeCookie=ValorDoCookie; Qualquer=Coisa
```

### Usando os Cookies:

Ele já está no formato que precisamos, basta agora inserir isto na sua requisição, para isso utilize o `stream_context_create`:

```
$cookies = file_get_contents('cookies.txt');
$opcoes = [
    'http'=> [
        'header'=>
            'Cookie: '. $cookies . "\r\n"
    ]
];

$context = stream_context_create($opcoes);
$resposta = file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1/teste.php', false, $context);
```

Isso irá enviar o cabeçalho de `Cookie:` contendo os cookies previamente salvos.

---

Se você precisa do formato Netscape, que é usado pelo `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` você também é capaz de armazena-lo de tal maneira. Claro, terá que adaptar todo o código acima para essa finalidade.

Já o `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION` não tem como ser "recriado" no caso acima. Essa função remove os cookies de sessões, isso é, descarta os cookies que não tem tempo de expiração. No caso acima apenas obtemos o nome e o valor, não armazenamos o tempo de expiração.

Comment: Se não for pedir muito. Você poderia montar uma função com esses opcionais?